# "rails db:migrate" error : relation "users" does not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am newbie with rails and here is my problem.

I created a very simple rails program and in the db > migrate > 2023.._add_columns_to_user.rb file, I added this code to this file

```
class AddColumnsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
def change
add_column :users, :full_name, :string
add_column :users, :from, :string
add_column :users, :about, :text
add_column :users, :language, :string
add_column :users, :status, :boolean
add_column :users, :status, :boolean, default: false
end
end
```

Then I ran this code

```
rails db:migrate
```

But it gave me this error

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

May be I must create the database first?
Could you please give me some advices for this problem?
Here is all of my code, if you need for reference.

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/Addcustomfieldsoutusermodel
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need to create the database first.  Then you need to create the users table. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: @dbugger the error is `PG::UndefinedTable` if the database didn't exist it would result in  `ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError` instead.

Comment: @max just laying out the steps, which clearly was needed

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter a table that hasn't yet been created. Your migration should be wrapped in a table defintion:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :full_name # shorthand for add_column :users, :full_name, :string
      t.string :from
      t.text :about
      t.boolean :status, default: false # why on earth is this a boolean?
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This results in `CREATE TABLE users (...)` while your migration would result in `ALTER TABLE users (...)`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I still got so many errors with your code, could you please check your code again?

Comment: Sorry there was a stray comma at - `t.boolean, :status, default: false` which should be  `t.boolean, :status, default: false`.